# Automatically play video file at a specific time

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am wondering if there is a way to create a batch file using Powershell or Notepad++ that will automatically start a .MP4 and/or .MKV file at a specific time.

I am using plex and would like to know if I could automatically play a movie file that is stored in my plex folder; while somehow, having that movie play on my 60" Vizio TV in the other room at a specific time. Would that even be possible?

Comment: Kind of sounds like you just need to use the Windows Task Scheduler and not worry about scripting anything.

Comment: Also, Powershell and batch are totally separate languages.

Comment: Too add to SomethingDark his comment : Powershell is a language, Notepad++ is a tool, something completely different.

Comment: It is possible when you have a media player that accepts passing time as a command line parameter. I think VLC [can do that](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) but recommending a tool is off-topic here.

Comment: @bluuf - true, I suppose, but you can write batch scripts with Notepad++, so what he was asking in that regard made sense.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could have done some simple googling to find the answer. I would recommend making a .bat file to open the file by file path [see link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080801230835AAj9n3T) on this. Then instead of automating the whole thing using batch you could use a task in task scheduler. This is a very straightforward task using the GUI. Basic instructions to create task:

1. Open task scheduler from start
2. Name task -> add description etc(optional)
3. Open triggers -> new -> set time settings
4. Open actions -> new -> browse for .bat file
5. Click Ok and you should be good.
   If you need more detailed instructions on task scheduler there's a lot of help out there on google or youtube. Also you didn't say so I am assuming your TV is hooked up to a computer of some type for any of this to work.